# Python how to insert bytes at offset?

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
some_bytes = bytes(8)
more_bytes = struct.pack(">I", 2)
```

How would I insert more_bytes into some_bytes at offset zero? I have some_bytes which is eight null bytes, and I have more_bytes which is 0x00000002. I want to get this as a result: 0000000200000000. I don't want to *add* more_bytes to some_bytes but rather insert those bytes into a specific offset of some_bytes since some_bytes is just null bytes used for alignment.

Comment: If let's say `some_bytes = 0x1234567890ABCDEF` what would you like the output to be after "insert" (at offset 0)?

Comment: If some_bytes = 0x1234567890ABCDEF and more_bytes = 0x00000002, then the output would be -> 0x0000000290ABCDEF

Comment: That means you are looking for a fixed length resultant bytearray. You are inserting `more_bytes` into a specific index of `some_bytes` and if that resultant bytearray exceeds the size, you are filling the last few indices in resultant bytearray with same number of last few indices in `some_bytes`. Is that correct?\

Answer (score 0):

The reason of my question in the comment was because the desired behavior wasn't clear:

- An *insert* would imply shifting the existing content after the inserted one to the right (which would then raise questions about sizes, and so on)
- A *replace* (desired) is simply "overwriting" a part of the original

You can use [[Python.Docs]: struct.pack_into(format, buffer, offset, v1, v2, ...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack_into):

> ```py
> >>> import struct
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> b = struct.pack(">Q", 0x1234567890ABCDEF)
> >>> b
> b'\x124Vx\x90\xab\xcd\xef'
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> def replace_bytes(buf, ofs, fmt, *args):
> ...     ba = bytearray(buf)
> ...     struct.pack_into(fmt, ba, ofs, *args)
> ...     return bytes(ba)
> ...
> >>>
> >>> replace_bytes(b, 0, ">I", 2)
> b'\x00\x00\x00\x02\x90\xab\xcd\xef'
> >>>
> >>> replace_bytes(b, 1, ">IH", 2, 1)
> b'\x12\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x01\xef'
> ```